# Apply a color map / gradient map to an image using Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, colors, colormap

Most image editing software has gradient map functions. Gradient maps take the brightness of a given pixel and apply a gradient of colors according to brightness. Photoshop and other software have ways to automate this, but they can't do exactly what I want, so I thought Python might do the trick. Unfortunately I'm having a very hard time understanding or applying any of the results that come up when I search for gradient maps or color maps with Python.

[image: Gradient maps]

All the potential solution threads I found used numpy or matplotlib which have lots of mathy lines that go right over my head... I would love some help with this. Initially I had something going with Processing, but I found the task of exporting tons of images with Processing to be weird and hacky. Plus I like Python, and want to learn how to edit and generate art with it.

This is what I'm working with right now.

```
from PIL import Image

myPalette = ['#1A1423', '#684756', '#AB8476']

def colorMap(pixel, palette): 
    # Calculate the brightness of pixel 
    R, G, B = pixel 
    brightness = sum([R, G, B])/3
 
    # Map gradient of colors to brightness
    # ???...
    
    return mappedColor

 
img = Image.open('image_input.png') 
pixels = img.load()
 
for x in range(img.size[0]): 
    for y in range(img.size[1]): 
        pixel = img.getpixel((x, y)) 
        pixels[x, y] = colorMap(pixel, myPalette)
 
img.save('image_output.png')
```

Loading, calculating brightness, and saving are easy. I just have no idea how to apply a gradient of my palette to the pixel.

Comment: This might be useful for you: https://bsouthga.dev/posts/color-gradients-with-python

Comment: You can call this pseudo-coloring.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that quite easily with **ImageMagick** or with PIL/Numpy/OpenCV.

The first thing is to get hold of the colormap - the vertical bar down the right side of your image. I don't have or know **Clip Studio**, so maybe it will let you export the colormap, or create a greyscale gradient and apply the colormap to it, then save the result as a PNG. In my case, I loaded  your image into Photoshop, cut out the gradient and rotated it to make an image *exactly* 256-pixels wide by 1-pixel high. Enlarged, that looks like this:

**colourmap.png**

[image]

I also cropped your swirl thing off the left side of your image - please post images separately in future.

**swirl.png**

[image]

---

Now for applying it. First, just with **ImageMagick** in Terminal. I loaded your swirl image and separated it into its constituent RGB channels then averaged the channels and applied the colourmap, also known as [CLUT](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#clut) or *"Colour Lookup Table"*:

```
magick swirl.png -channel RGB -separate -evaluate-sequence mean colourmap.png -clut result.png
```

[image]

---

Next, same thing with PIL/Numpy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load image, make into Numpy array and average RGB channels
im = Image.open('swirl.png').convert('RGB')
na = np.array(im)
grey = np.mean(na, axis=2).astype(np.uint8)
Image.fromarray(grey).save('DEBUG-grey.png')   # DEBUG only

# Load colourmap
cmap = Image.open('colourmap.png').convert('RGB')

# Make output image, same height and width as grey image, but 3-channel RGB
result = np.zeros((*grey.shape,3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Take entries from RGB colourmap according to greyscale values in image
np.take(cmap.getdata(), grey, axis=0, out=result)

# Save result
Image.fromarray(result).save('result.png')
```

---

You can also generate piece-wise linear colormaps like this:

```
 magick -size 160x1 gradient:navy-"rgb(220,110,110)"   \
        -size  60x1 gradient:"rgb(220,110,110)"-yellow \
        -size  35x1 gradient:yellow-white              \
        +append colourmap.png
```

[image]

That makes three segments each with a linear gradient:

- 160x1 in navy to salmon,
- 60x1 in salmon to yellow and
- 35x1 in yellow to white

then appends them together.

---

If you make all the segments of the colour map the same length, you will get a different interpretation:

```
magick -size 85x1 \
   gradient:navy-"rgb(220,110,110)"   \
   gradient:"rgb(220,110,110)"-yellow \
   gradient:yellow-white +append -resize 256x1\! colourmap.png
```

[image]

That leads to this:

[image]

Comment: Ty for detailed reply! I also should have clarified my intent. I am making an "automatic mod maker" for a videogame that applies color maps to dozens of textures according to palettes I define. This numpy code works, but I want the multicolor gradient to be generated programmatically by a list of colors. I managed to get a colormap function working in [my current code](https://pastebin.com/rntVnZNu), but it only blends between 2 colors and I'm not sure how to make it more flexible.

I'll noodle around with your code and suggestions. Still digesting these lines you wrote.

Comment: Ok, but you'd need to specify *where* each colour in the map. If you look at the last part of my answer, it generates a map *navy-salmon-yellow-white* but each segment has a different length, 160:60:35. If you specify and share some maps in your question, I'll take another look. You could save them as CSV, or 256x1 PNG, or as Python dict... maybe Clip Studio can export something useful?

Comment: I suppose I could export the gradient PNG with clip studio for now, but it would be nice to remove that step. I'm generating the gradient palettes with [this website](https://coolors.co). Pasting these hex codes into Clip Studio and exporting an image for the gradient feels like an unnecessary step. Plus, this site gives you a formatted list/array of the colors, and I might even be able to get them right from the page without any hardcoding. I understand that the colors have "positions" on the gradient that have to be defined.

Comment: The "coolors.co" website will export CSV if you click `export`->`code` Or it will export a PNG that you could crop the top line off and find the unique colours in it. Still not sure how you want to specify the position of each colour vis-à-vis your grey tones.

Comment: Couldn't the positions be some generic distribution of values by default? Like `0.0, 0.5, 1.0`? I imagine I could make a class object that stores the color and position to make editing it easier, too.

Cropping the coolors image and using the numpy script you wrote sounds pretty clever though... How could I turn that cropped line of 5 colors into a usable gradient for the script?

Comment: The trouble is that you will get a different interpretation of your image depending on the *"stops"* or positions. I'll add a bit more to the bottom of my answer to demonstrate...

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to define a mapping table that associates a color to every gray value in the range [0, 255] (in your case, you can even map [0, 255 x 3] by not taking the average).

Now to get a smooth effect, you need to change the color components regularly. The options are unlimited. Here is a typical example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are two methods, one using Matplotlib and one using only OpenCV

**Method #1:** `OpenCV` + [`matplotlib.pyplot.get_cmap`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.get_cmap)

We first load in the image as grayscale. By default, OpenCV reads in an image as 3-channel, 8-bit BGR. We can directly load in an image as grayscale using [`cv2.imread()`](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) with the `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` parameter or use [`cv2.cvtColor()`](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html) to convert a BGR image to grayscale with the `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` parameter. Once we load in the image, we throw this grayscale image into Matplotlib to obtain our heatmap image. Matplotlib returns a RGB format so we must convert back to Numpy format and switch to BGR colorspace for use with OpenCV. Here's a example using the `inferno` colormap. See [choosing color maps in Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) for available built-in colormaps depending on your desired use case.

Input image `->` Heatmap image

[image]
[image]

Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)
colormap = plt.get_cmap('inferno')
heatmap = (colormap(image) * 2**16).astype(np.uint16)[:,:,:3]
heatmap = cv2.cvtColor(heatmap, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('heatmap', heatmap)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Method #2:** [`cv2.applyColorMap()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html)

We can use OpenCV's built in heatmap function. Here's the result using the `cv2.COLORMAP_HOT` heatmap

[image]

Code

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)
heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(image, cv2.COLORMAP_HOT)

cv2.imshow('heatmap', heatmap)
cv2.waitKey()
```

---

**Note:** Although OpenCV's built-in implementation is short and quick, I recommend using Method #1 since there is a larger colormap selection. Matplotlib has [hundreds of various colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#choosing-colormaps-in-matplotlib) and allows you to [create your own custom color maps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html) while OpenCV only has 12 to choose from. Here's the built in OpenCV colormap selection:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you didn't want matplotlib, but I don't think you need mathy lines to make it work. I tested it with a PNG of my own, so hopefully it works for yours as well. Here's an example that draws heavily on [this documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/custom_cmap.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# Read PNG and take average:
img = plt.imread('image_input.png')
Z = img.mean(-1)

#   Kestrel
color_list = [np.array([207,117,80])/255,
              np.array([219,179,127])/255,
              np.array([248,249,251])/255,
              np.array([185,191,205])/255,
              np.array([88,104,127])/255]

cmap_name = 'Kestrel'
N_bin=100
# Create the colormap
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(cmap_name, color_list, N=N_bin)
# Fewer bins will result in "coarser" colomap interpolation
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(Z, cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm fine with using those libraries, I just had a hard time applying the stuff I was reading. 

Your code does apply my intended effect, but how do I go about removing the background and labels of the saved figure? I'm applying gradients to dozens of texture files that have specific required sizes I cannot alter